# Ruby rails - redirect_to a different view with get parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a "create" function which shall redirect to a new view called "view". "view" uses get method, so I need to provide the parameters in the url.

"create" creates a new item 123, and redirects/renders "view" with url `/view?id=123`
I also want pass on some additional parameters while redirecting to this view, `/view?id=123&note=duplicate`

How do I do this?

```
  def create   
    @i = Book.createNewItem(params[:name])
    if @i[:error] == ""
      render action: 'view',
    else
      redirect_to book_home_path
    end
  end

  def view
    Book.getItem(params[:id]) #some backend update stuff
    @i = Book.find_by_book_num(params[:id])
    return @i
  end
```

Comment: `redirect_to :action => 'view', :id => @i[:id]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    render :action=>'view', :id=>123, :note=>"duplicate"
```

This will automatically generate 'get' url to view action, like this:

```
    "/view?id=123&note=duplicate"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional parameters in a hash, passed to the url helper like this:

```
redirect_to book_view_path(id: @i.id, note: 'duplicate')
```

or

```
redirect_to action: "view", id: 5, note: 'duplicate'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as sipmple

```
 redirect_to "/view?id="+@i+"&note=duplicate"
```

Try it...